# How to test an element of Vue 3 and Quasar componet which use its own props (arrtibutes) different of component's props?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, quasar-framework

In my Quasar (Vue 3) component I have an element of linear progress:

```
<q-linear-progress
    :stripe: true
    :value="percentageCounted(tested, total)/100"
/>
```

"tested" and "total" are component props, and percentageCounted is a function that counts the percentage ant it is imported from another file.

I try to test this element like this:

```
it(`computes correct progress value`, () => {
        
        let wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
          total:100,
          tested:60
        });

        const progressBar = wrapper.find('q-linear-progress');
        const actualValue = parseFloat(progressBar.attributes("value"));

        expect(progressBar.attributes("value"))).toBe(percentageCounted(tested, total)/100);
      });
```

But this test doesn't work. First, it can't find DOMWrapper but when I add a dot before 'q-linear-progress' expected it can't read the attribute "value".

Comment: This isn't done this way. Props and attributes are different things. Either test the behaviour instead of the implementation, or replace q-linear-progress with test double (which you should do any way in unit tests)

Comment: Thanks I will search in this direction